# MySQL - Composite Unique Key with datetime

Tags: mysql

I have a transaction table where several rows may be stored against three attributes (foo_id, bar_id), and the last attribute is deleted_at, the thought here is to ensure that I only have one active row at a time (deleted_at = '0000-00-00 00:00:00').

But I am getting the following error:

```
mysql> UPDATE epic_table SET deleted_at = NOW() WHERE (foo_id = '1' AND bar_id IN ('18'));
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '18-1-2015-08-08 16:35:46' for key 'epic_table_ibuk_1'
```

Here is the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `epic_table` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `foo_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `bar_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `deleted_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `epic_table_ibuk_1` (`foo_id`,`bar_id`,`deleted_at`),
  KEY `epic_table_ibfk_1` (`foo_id`),
  KEY `epic_table_ibfk_2` (`bar_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `epic_table_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`foo_id`) REFERENCES `foo` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `epic_table_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`bar_id`) REFERENCES `bar` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=37 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The only thing that immediately stands out is that MySQL may not be considering the time portion of the datetime value, and therefore complaining about another row with `18-1-2015-08-08`.

Any ideas how I can maintain the multiple row flexibility while being able to enforce that only one row is 'active' at any given time?

Comment: Does `(foo_id = '1' AND bar_id IN ('18'))` match exactly _one_ row? If it actually matches more than one, the new value `NOW()` will cause a key constraint violation. If there are more than one but you want to choose just one with `LIMIT` (which would avoid the uniqueness violation), on what other criteria would you sort them?

Comment: No, there could be X number of rows with foo_id = 1, bar_id = 18, the only diff between them would be deleted_at value, with only one of the many having a deleted_at = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'

Comment: @MikePurcell if you have many rows with foo_id=1 and bar_id=18, your update statement is asking all of those rows to be updated with deleted_at = NOW() and therefore causing non-uniqueness. Could you change your where clause to use `and deleted_at = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'`?

Comment: ....... holy crap... not sure why I didn't catch that.... thanks.

Comment: @MikePurcell - would you like me to add my comment as an answer to cause this question to be cleanly closed? Your choice.

Comment: Ya... so basic but you caught my error and should be rewarded thusly. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Changing from a comment to an answer...

The statement:

```
UPDATE epic_table SET deleted_at = NOW() 
WHERE (foo_id = '1' AND bar_id IN ('18'));
```

attempts to set `deleted_at` for all rows with `foo_id = 1` and `bar_id = 18`. Since foo_id, bar_id and deleted_at combination is marked as unique, such change ends up violating the unique constraint.

Only a slight change may be needed to the statement like so, knowing that only one record may have `deleted_at = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'`:

```
UPDATE epic_table SET deleted_at = NOW() 
WHERE (foo_id = '1' AND bar_id IN ('18') and deleted_at = '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
```